# button "Post" in SLComposeViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, ios8

I am developing a share extension for my application and wanted to know if it was possible to change the text of the button "Post" in SLComposeViewController.
I tried in all ways but I just can not figure out if it can do
Thanks a lot in advance
Luca

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to change the text of Post and cancel button in SLComposeViewController.

Apple doesn't provide any api for this.
So you can't.